# British vs American Edits

Tags: discussion, languages

An answer of mine was corrected, among other things, to employ the word "utilise" as opposed to the word "utilize".  I feel this takes a license that is beyond editorial and of no consequence as to the content of the response (or question) itself...what are the community's feelings on "re-culturization" of language?

Comment: Well, no need for a drama, just roll it back.  Come back when they change your parentheses into brackets.

Comment: Oh, no drama, didn't mean it to come off that way :)

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us

Comment: Closing as duplicate also.  Agreed, @Frédéric

Comment: I assume you mean [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600164/is-it-possible-to-convert-your-iphone-in-a-multi-user-finger-print-scanner/30600327#30600327) where the edit was a suggestion that had to be approved... While I think the spelling part was an incorrect edit, their fixing of your link description was a smart one. You should also try to pull anything relavant from your link to your answer, in case that link goes down. (That is, assuming that the license on the linked "sample" is compatible with the SO code license.)

Comment: Keep in mind that the editor might not be aware of the different localized spelling and just thought it was a typo :)

Comment: Agree with all, thanks everyone.

Comment: I just had this done to me. The editor changed my text from "minimise", "behaviours" and "analyse" to the American counterpart. I find it annoying because the editor did it seeking cheap points. As far as I know, the standardisation process happens at the label of tags, the body can be written in your language.

Comment: Rewarding dialect-editing behavior with points is not a good way to make Stack Overflow a welcoming space. I had this happen too! I'm comforted to find this post. As the author of two books in U.S. English, I checked for answers to my frustrating Android UI issue. Instead of help, what came was a crossing out of my "customize" as a misspelling. Worse, other users signed off on these repairs to my bad "grammar." I love British English but this is perverse. Is there a way we can stop these point-grubbing incidents, whether from U.S. to UK English or the reverse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that's the only thing an edit changes in an post, it's an invalid edit.

Edits are meant to improve the quality of a post.
Whether the post was written in American English or British doesn't influence its quality.

Your best course of action would be to just roll back the edit (once). If the person keeps editing the post, flag the post with a custom message explaining the situation. Otherwise, you'd just have a edit war that won't end well.